# How to rank search results by edgengram match percentage

Tags: elasticsearch

When using edge-ngram index, usually you also want to rank results by match percentage.
for example:
input is 
appl,
apple,
aa,

if query is aa, then ranking should be 
aa > appl > apple

however the default ranking is using tfidf, so the rank is the same.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "title": "apple" 
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "title": "appl" 
}

GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "ap", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the result is
apple and appl, both of their score is the same

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same analyzer (autocomplete) as your search_analyzer instead of "autocomplete_search", you should get the scores as you expect them to be.

EDIT: To limit matches, you can use a bool query with 2 clauses. One with must, without specifying any analyzer (will use your search_analyzer). The other in a should block with "analyzer": "autocomplete" to increase the score of queries which match more tokens.

Comment: But if I do not use autocomplete_search, it will match a much wider search scope.